# Pylance: "property" is incompatible with "int"

Tags: python, interface, getter-setter, type-hinting, pylance

```
from typing_extensions import Protocol


class IFoo(Protocol):
    value: int


class Foo(IFoo):
    @property
    def value(self) -> int:
        return 2

    _value: int

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value: int):
        self._value = value
```

Pylance in strict mode(basic mode doesn't) is giving an error at the getter and the setter saying that:

"value" overrides symbol of the same name in class "IFoo"
"property" is incompatible with "int".

I could make this work by changing the Protocol to:

```
class IFoo(Protocol):
    @property
    def value(self) -> int:
        raise NotImplemented
```

But this now makes this invalid:

```
class Foo(IFoo):
    value: int
```

This doesn't makes sense, the Foo would still have the property `value` that is an int, why being a getter should makes it different (in typescript this doesn't make a difference)?
How can I fix this?

Comment: This doesn't throw an error when I run this, which python version are you using?

Comment: 3.9.5 

Are Pylance in strict mode? Basic mode doesn't show this error.

Comment: An `int`-valued class attribute is not the same thing as `property`-valued attribute whose getter returns an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [Defining a protocol](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#defining-a-protocol) section of the relevant pep (PEP 544), the example  implementation (in their case, `class Resource`) does not directly inherit from the protocol - their `class SupportsClose` functions as a reference type for type hinting validators.

Your example is also reminiscent of the long established `zope.interface` package, which this PEP also [referenced](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#existing-approaches-to-structural-subtyping).  Note that the example usage the PEP have cited the following example (irrelevant lines trimmed):

```
from zope.interface import Interface, implementer

class IEmployee(Interface):
   ...

@implementer(IEmployee)
class Employee:
   ...
```

The `Employee` class does *not* directly subclass from `IEmployee` (a common mistake for newbie Zope/Plone developers back in the days), it's simply decorated with the `zope.interface.implementer(IEmployee)` class decorator to denote that the class `Employee` implements from the interface `IEmployee`.

Likewise, reading further down under the section [Protocol members](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#protocol-members), we have an example of the template and concrete classes (again, example trimmed):

```
from typing import Protocol

class Template(Protocol):
    name: str        # This is a protocol member
    value: int = 0   # This one too (with default)

class Concrete:
    def __init__(self, name: str, value: int) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

var: Template = Concrete('value', 42)  # OK
```

Again, note that the `Concrete` implementation does *not* inherit from the `Template`, yet, the variable `var` is denoted to have an expected type of `Template`.  Note that the `Concrete` instance can be assigned to it as it matches the expected protocol as defined for `Template`.

So all that being said, given your example, you may wish to define `class Foo:` as is rather than having it inherit from `IFoo` as you had originally, and fill in the type information such that things that expect `IFoo` be type hinted as appropriately in the relevant context (e.g. `some_foo: IFoo = Foo(...)` or `def some_func(foo: IFoo):`).

As an addendum, you may wish to define `Foo` as such:

```
class Foo:
    _value: int

    @property
    def value(self) -> int:
        return 2

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value: int):
        self._value = value
```

Having the `_value` definition in between the property and its setter seems to confuse `mypy` due to [this issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1465).