# Python @property method violating Protocol variable type annotation

Tags: python, interface, getter-setter, pylance, pep

I have an [interface](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/)

```py
class Moveable(Protocol):
    position: Tuple[int, int]
```

I implement the interface with a class that happens to use a getter to imitate the attribute `position: Tuple[int, int]`

```py
class Player:
    _x: int
    _y: int

    @property
    def position(self) -> Tuple[int, int]:
        return (self._x, self._y)
```

I instantiate a `Moveable` variable to `Player()`, but Pylance raises an error

```py
entity: Moveable = Player()
```

```
(class) Player()
Expression of type "Player" cannot be assigned to declared type "Moveable"
  "Player" is incompatible with protocol "Moveable"
    "position" is invariant because it is mutable
    "position" is an incompatible type
      "property" is incompatible with "Tuple[int, int]" PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
```

The error goes away if I change the type annotation on the interface to `property`

```py
class Moveable(Protocol):
    position: property # fixes Pylance alert
```

This isn't tenable as I may have classes that do not use a getter to produce a `position` but instead have it directly as an attribute.
I want my interface to be agnostic as to whether classes implement a `position: Tuple[int, int]` member using a `@property` or as a direct attribute.

A non-ideal attempt at a solution was to use a `Union`, but that oddly isn't acceptable to Pylance either

```py
class Moveable(Protocol):
    position: Union[Tuple[int, int], property]
```

```
class) Player()
Expression of type "Player" cannot be assigned to declared type "Moveable"
  "Player" is incompatible with protocol "Moveable"
    "position" is invariant because it is mutable
    "position" is an incompatible type
      Type "property" cannot be assigned to type "Tuple[int, int] | property"
        "property" is incompatible with "Tuple[int, int]" PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
```

Seems like this should be supported. Is it? Anyway to achieve the effect?

Comment: Related [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69006473/pylance-property-is-incompatible-with-int).

Comment: I have a similar issue. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `@property` in both the protocol and the conforming class of protocol ([at least according to the latest mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html?highlight=%40property#covariant-subtyping-of-mutable-protocol-members-is-rejected), be aware that the different type checkers may behave differently). Here's the complete example based on the question:

```
from typing import Protocol, Tuple


class Movable(Protocol):
    @property
    def position(self) -> Tuple[int, int]:
        ...


class Player:
    _x: int
    _y: int

    def __init__(self, x: int = 0, y: int = 0):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y

    @property
    def position(self) -> Tuple[int, int]:
        return (self._x, self._y)


def print_position(obj: Movable) -> None:
    print(obj.position)


p = Player(x=1, y=2)
print_position(p)
```